# Cast(to_number(to_char())) not returning second values

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to convert a timestamp to a number but it is failing to return second values.

when looking at the date 2012/01/04 00:00:21 I am expecting the below code to return for example 20100104000021.
Instead I am getting 20100104000000 with the 21 at the end being converted to 00. This is happening for all records and I am unsure why.

```
        to_number(TO_CHAR(p_timestamp,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))
```

Could anyone advise?

EDIT: I have removed CAST however I am still encountering the same issue.

Comment: What is the datatype of variable p_timestamp?

Comment: Did you select just p_timestamp to make sure it has the correct value, as `SELECT TO_CHAR(p_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') FROM YourTable;`?

Comment: Works fine for me in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0f09/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use `To_Number` function:

```
select To_Number(To_Char(p_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))
  from MyTable
```

or `cast` to appropriate Number:

```
-- change Number(20) to required type
select Cast(To_Char(p_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as Number(20))
  from MyTable
```

P.S. (Side note): use `VarChar2` instead of `VarChar` in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

The CAST function is not correctly used. You can drop it, as:

```
SELECT to_number(TO_CHAR(p_timestamp,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) FROM YourTable;
```